# Where to find block cipher modes in a TLS Cipher Suite

Tags: ssl, block-cipher

I'm working on finding out the TLS Cipher Suite being used on a TLS Connection by using System.Net Trace Listener, in a C# program. I get the following details in the Trace log file:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [42820] ProcessAuthentication(Protocol=Tls12, Cipher=Aes256 256 bit strength, Hash=Sha384 0 bit strength, Key Exchange=44550 255 bit strength).
```

Looking at the [anatomy of a Cipher Suite](https://hincu.io/exploring-the-anatomy-of-a-tls-cipher-suite/), from the above trace file data, I have the following all the components to make up a cipher suite as below, except the "block cipher mode":

`TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`

Where or how I can find the value "GCM" above. Some of the block cipher modes are GCM, CBC, CCM.

Comment: Look at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52566/why-was-aes-cbc-removed-in-tls-1-3 : CBC has been removed in TLS 1.3 and should not be used earlier either. See https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4 and the Recommended column being `N` for CBC based ones. And https://security.googleblog.com/2013/11/a-roster-of-tls-cipher-suites-weaknesses.html.  But other than that in all generality I think you do not get enough information from the underlying library.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, the information and the links you provided were very helpful to get some understanding on CBC. Also its sad to know that the underlying library doesn't seem to get enough information on the "block cipher modes" being used. My project uses .Net Framework 4.7.1. In case anyone knows of a way to find the "block cipher modes", please let me know.

Comment: System.Security.Cryptography Namespace has details on Block Cipher Mode and can be used as below (from https://gist.github.com/odan/138dbd41a0c5ef43cbf529b03d814d7c):

Aes encryptor = Aes.Create();
encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

CipherMode enum has the following values, I'm using .Net Framework v4.7.1:

public enum CipherMode
{
    CBC = 1,        
    ECB = 2,        
    OFB = 3,        
    CFB = 4,        
    CTS = 5
}

But I'm still not sure how to figure out the CipherMode on a TLS Connection.